# Rollover image has unwanted grey bar under it

Tags: html, css, png, dreamweaver, transparent

My rollover image is 350 by 250 transparent .png with a circular image inside. The rollover image seems to have an unwanted grey bar appear at the bottom...

I used the basic rollover image process in Dreamweaver, by clicking "Insert" - "Image Objects" - "Rollover Image" then followed the proper steps.

Comment: Can you please provide some relevant HTML/CSS.. we currently have no way of seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS and see if it fixes it:

```
area {
    outline : none !important;
}
```

Comment: I posted it to the top of my CSS style sheet but it didnt change much

Comment: go to jsfiddle.com put your code on there and then post the link on here so the community can try and fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
a img { border: none;
}
```

Sometimes (not all) but sometimes, Dreamweaver adds a border around some images, especially rollover or links. This line of CSS removes that border from **all** images. If you specifically want borders on a certain image, you'll have to add some CSS for that particular image.